# DFSR-related WMI info is missing

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, wmi

OS: Server 2012 Core and Server 2012 R2 Core.
DFS-Replication is installed and appears healthy.

I am using WMI to collect information from DFSR replication members. The queries work on many of the computers, but there are a couple of replication members on which the queries do not work.

It is the DfsrReplicatedFolderInfo class from the root\MicrosoftDFS namespace.

If I execute the following Powershell command:

`Get-WmiObject -Namespace 'root\MicrosoftDFS' -Class DfsrReplicatedFolderInfo`

The result is null.  No error, but absolutely no output.

If I execute the following corresponding wmic command:

`wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoftdfs path DfsrReplicatedFolderInfo get`

it returns:

`No Instance(s) Available.`

This happens regardless of whether the commands are executed locally or remotely.

`winmgmt /verifyrepository` returns:

`WMI repository is consistent`

Using `wbemtest`, I am able to view the DfsrReplicatedFolderInfo class definition, but there appear to be no instances of it.

Other DFSR-related classes in the same namespace appear to be working correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Problem solved. DFSR was in fact *not* healthy. It was not a WMI problem. The server had experienced a dirty shutdown, and DFSR stopped replicating because of it.

Restarting replication on the affected volume with

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoftdfs path dfsrVolumeConfig where volumeGuid="DC8EEE19-97E2-4E26-8AAD-CF1235B8DCCC" call ResumeReplication
```

Resolved the issue.

Then I turned auto recovery back on by editing the registry:

```
HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\DFSR\Parameters\
       StopReplicationOnAutoRecovery = 0
```

So that this wouldn't happen again in the future.

I'm really embarrassed for not checking the logs more thoroughly in the first place.

Comment: How did you get the value for the volumeGuid?

Comment: @mwfearnley You get the VolumeGuid with the command "mountvol". There might be better ones, but this made it for me while reading the above solution.